# What are the effects of using different types of ground mustard?

Tags: ingredient-selection

I made a cheese souffle recipe that called for 1 tsp of dry mustard. I used ground mustard that was 40% yellow and 60% black.(And it wasn't fine like powder)  Everything went perfectly with the souffle but the taste wasn't all that amazing. In fact, I couldn't stand eating it, perhaps because of the mustard spice I used, it just didn't taste good. I even reduced the amount of dry mustard to ~90% of 1 tsp, because I feared that its pungent taste would overcome everything else. So, now I am left wondering where did I go wrong? Is there a difference in taste with my described mustard and 100% yellow mustard? Would this difference cause such a huge taste differences?

I used Alton Brown's recipe: http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/cheese-souffle-recipe.html.

The only change I made is add a pinch of nutmeg and cayenne pepper instead of the garlic powder.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but: do you like mustard taste in principle? It is a huge variation. There are people who can eat mustard by the spoon and love it, others for whom a hint of it destroys the dish. Maybe you have a mid-to-low tolerance for mustard and the recipe is calibrated for people who like it in large amounts?

Comment: @rumtscho Apart from never consuming dijon mustard by a spoon!!, I don't specifically hate mustard. Its a perfect match for salads, steak, and most obviously hot dogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brown/black mustard seed is hotter and more intense than yellow. So, powdered mustard seed that is predominantly brown/black is going to pack quite a wallop compared to powdered yellow mustard seed. In the US, recipes calling for powdered mustard are going to expect you to use yellow. See [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/01/spice-hunting-mustard-seed-how-to-use-cook-where-to-find.html) for an interesting article on the subject.

Comment: Good answer. I expect that if he uses yellow mustard powder he would see a huge difference in his resulting dish.